# SQL Server Cyrillic Writing '?????'

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I am running a SQL Server 2008 R2 and I have a database containing multilingual words.

For Cyrillic words I only see '???????'

The data type is nvarchar(255), the collection is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS (which was my default)

I have no idea what else can I do, any idea??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you add data to the nvarchar column, use the prefix N

```
Insert into table(nvarchar_col)
select N'your Cyrillic words'
```